# ipython tab completion of method parameters showing builtins

Tags: ipython

IPython tab completion for method parameters is showing more information than I'm expecting to see:

```
snowch$ ipython3
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 21 2017, 18:29:43)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from my_package import MyClass

In [2]: cf = MyClass(<TAB>
                       abs()                                 api_key=
                       all()                                 api_key_filename=
                       any()                                 ArithmeticError                       >
                       api_endpoint=                         ascii()
                       ...
```

This also happens on instance methods:

```
In [3]: cf.auth(<TAB>
                 abs()                                 ascii()
                       ...
```

**Q) Should I be seeing builtin methods like `abs()` when I tab complete on my instance methods and constructors?**.

My IPCompleter configuration looks like this:

```
In [4]: %config IPCompleter
IPCompleter options
-----------------
IPCompleter.backslash_combining_completions=<Bool>
    Current: True
IPCompleter.debug=<Bool>
    Current: False
IPCompleter.greedy=<Bool>
    Current: False
IPCompleter.jedi_compute_type_timeout=<Int>
    Current: 400
IPCompleter.limit_to__all__=<Bool>
    Current: False
IPCompleter.merge_completions=<Bool>
    Current: True
IPCompleter.omit__names=<Enum>
    Current: 2
IPCompleter.use_jedi=<Bool>
    Current: True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should, because having function call in methods or constructor is perfectly valid. Actually you can write any expressions in any field when you call a callable.

```
MyProgressMeter(any(params))
range(abs(value_a - value_b))
obj.frobulate(len(set(items)))
print(len(my_list))
```

Are reasonable, so on `MyProgressMeter(<tab>`, `obj.frobulate(<tab>`,  `print(<tab>` and `range(<tab>` you're shown everything that is in local/global namespace that make sense, as well as named parameters.
Instance methods are no different of course.

Note: it is not well known but `range` is actually a constructor:

```
>>> type(range)
<class 'type'>
```

Comment: Thanks - useful to know that this is normal behaviour.  It is a shame though because it impacts on usability.  I guess I should be using `cf = MyClass?` and `cf.auth?` if I just want to see the method signatures.

Comment: Yes, for now IPython does not have a way to show a tooltip like the notebook (what Shift-Tab does), we would have to decide of a shortcut and implement that... PRs welcome.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I found `%pdef` was what I was looking for in terms of output brevity.

Comment: One interesting thing I noticed with the behaviour is that tab completion doesn't give any preference to the method parameters with its output  Presumably, most people will want to see the method parameters output before (above) the builtins?

Comment: Likely yes, we just need to implement a sorting heuristic... do I hear a PR coming from you ?